# When calling own method, Old String values are left over

Tags: java, recursion

When I get the unwanted input I called the method again, but then on the second iteration there is still a char left on the String. Why doesn't it make a brand new string and replace the older value?

SO first i type in "mmmm" into the scanner, which sets off the condition in the if statement and calls `createSocial()`, which then reruns the loop, and I type in a new input of 5555. Now this is what I don't get: when I print out the new Strings they show up as 5555, but then printing them in the loop has the left over "m", why?

```
    public class test {
    public static String createSocial() {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            String social = sc.nextLine();
            String digit = social; 
            System.out.println(social + "     SOCIAL");
            System.out.println(digit + "     DIGIT");

            if (social.length() != 4) {
                System.out.println("You did not type 4 digits, try again");  
                createSocial(); 
            }
            //check non-integers        
            while(digit.length() > 0) {
                System.out.println( digit.charAt(0) + "<---");  
                if(Character.isDigit( digit.charAt(0) ) == false) {
                    System.out.println("You did not type your last 4 digits correctly, try again"); 

                    createSocial();  
                }
                digit = digit.substring(1); 
            }   
            return social; 
        }
}
```

This is my output :

```
    enter the last 4 digits of your Social Security number
    mmmm    //(This is my first input for the scanner)
    mmmm     SOCIAL
    mmmm     DIGIT
    m<---
    You did not type your last 4 digits correctly, try again
    5555   //(this is my input for the scanner the second time around)
    5555     SOCIAL
    5555     DIGIT
    5<---
    5<---
    5<---
    5<---
    m<---
    You did not type your last 4 digits correctly, try again
```

Comment: When you first call `createSocial()`, it prompts for input, you enter "mmmm", then your code gets into the `while` loop. Before the `while` loop completes, your code is making an entirely new call to `createSocial()`. After the second call to `createSocial()` completes (you entered input of "5555"), your program continues with the _rest_ of the `while` loop from the _first_ time you called `createSocial()`. In that first invocation, the `digit` variable contains the "m" input value.

Comment: This issue is because of recursion. When you call the method again all those variables are again added to the stack(on top of the first). When the second call completes the first call still has another trip around the loop

Comment: add a `return` before the call to `createSocial()`.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn you mean 'after' right?

Comment: @David No, lexically before: `return createSocial()`.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn yes I get ya

Comment: Don't use recursion for mere iteration.

Comment: Note that `if («something» == false)` can always be replaced by just `if (!«something»)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you see the **m** as in:

```
5<---
5<---
5<---
5<---
m<---
```

is simply because you don't clear the **social** string variable before you embark on your recursion call. In reality when making this recursion call you should be doing it this way:

```
social = createSocial();
```

This way you are guaranteed **social** will always hold the true value from that recursion call and not a value from a ***previous*** recursion call. If you don't take the return value from the **createSocial()** method you will never get the new result because the scope of the **social** variable is local to the method itself. You need to accept the return value just as you do on your very first initial call to the **createSocial()** method.

But that's not all, you also need to update the **digit** variable content after every recursive call (`digit = social;`). In my opinion this is more complicated than necessary. I understand why you've added the **digit** variable but if you take a close look at the code you could have accomplished the same thing by just continuing to utilize the **social** variable to carry out the numerical breakdown. You just need to hold the original value within **social** before the numerical breakdown is carried out within a variable that can be returned by the method, for example:

```
private static int methodCalls = 0; // Class Global Member Variable

public static String createSocial() {
    methodCalls++;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String social = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println(social + "     SOCIAL");
    if (social.length() != 4) {
        System.out.println("You did not type 4 digits, try again");
        social = createSocial();
    }

    // returnResult will eventually will hold the 
    // valid result to return.
    String returnResult = social;

    //check non-integers      
    while (social.length() > 0) {
        System.out.println(social.charAt(0) + " <--- Method call: " + methodCalls);
        if (Character.isDigit(social.charAt(0)) == false) {
            System.out.println("You did not type your last 4 digits correctly, try again");
            social = createSocial();
        }
        social = social.substring(1);
    }
    methodCalls--;
    return returnResult;
}
```

Using your posted example parameters (mmmmm and 5555) you might use the above code like this:

```
System.out.println(createSocial());
```

and after entering **mmmmm** and **5555** the output result to console would look like this:

```
mmmmm
mmmmm     SOCIAL
You did not type 4 digits, try again
5555
5555     SOCIAL
5 <--- Method call: 2
5 <--- Method call: 2
5 <--- Method call: 2
5 <--- Method call: 2
5 <--- Method call: 1
5 <--- Method call: 1
5 <--- Method call: 1
5 <--- Method call: 1
5555
```

Why all the `5 <---`? Because of the single recursive call. The 5's that are labeled **Method call: 1** is the initial call to the **createSocial**() method. Any method call over 1 is a recursive call. Upon each call four `5 <---`'s are listed.

This can all be done in a much easier fashion and recursion is not required to carry out this task, a loop can be used instead, for example:

```
public static String createSocial() {
    String ls = System.lineSeparator();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String social = "";
    while (social.equals("")) {
        System.out.print("Please enter the last four digits of " + ls
                + "your Social Security Number: --> ");

        social = sc.nextLine();
        if (!social.matches("\\d{4}")) {
            System.err.println("Invalid Entry! Please Try Again..." + ls);
            social = "";
        }
    }
    return social;
}
```

But if recursion is a requirement then you can do it this way:

```
public static String createSocial() {
    String ls = System.lineSeparator();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String social = "";
    System.out.print("Please enter the last four digits of " + ls
                + "your Social Security Number: --> ");
    social = sc.nextLine();
    if (!social.matches("\\d{4}")) {
        System.err.println("Invalid Entry! Please Try Again..." + ls);
        social = createSocial();
    }
    return social;
}
```

Using Java's [String#matches()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_matches.htm) method along with a small [Regular Expression](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) to check for data entry validity removes the need for a lot of code and makes things much easier to read. The Regular Expression (RegEx) used within the **matches()** method of the **IF** statement condition in the two above code examples

```
if (!social.matches("\\d{4}")) {
```

*basically* means this: If the User entry string is **not** a four digit integer value then display an "Invalid Entry!" message.